# Как предотвратить ошибку RecursionError при компиляции приложения на Tkinter?

Tags: python, рекурсия, компиляция

Когда я решил создать своё приложение на Tkinter я использовал библиотеку py2applet для компиляции приложения.Я создал папку с главным кодом, папку с изображением, воспользовался командой "py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py" и в папке с проектом появилась  setup.py в которой я указал все пути до изображений, указал все нужные библиотеки, оставалось только выполнить команду "python setup.py py2app", как код итоге  выдал ошибку RecursionError. Что нужно сделать чтобы все заработало?

```
(base) MacBook-Pro-Admin-2:~ admin$ cd /Users/admin/Folder2 
(base) MacBook-Pro-Admin-2:Folder2 admin$ python3 setup.py py2app
running py2app
creating /Users/admin/Folder2/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.9-standalone/app
creating /Users/admin/Folder2/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.9-standalone/app/collect
creating /Users/admin/Folder2/build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.9-standalone/app/temp
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.9-standalone/app/lib-dynload
creating build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/python3.9-standalone/app/Frameworks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Folder2/setup.py", line 20, in <module>
    setup(
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 984, in run
    self._run()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1214, in _run
    self.run_normal()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1307, in run_normal
    mf = self.get_modulefinder()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1145, in get_modulefinder
    return find_modules(
    q = self._import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1420, in _import_module
    m = self._load_module(fqname, fp, pathname, stuff)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1450, in _load_module
    m = self._load_package(fqname, pathname, packagepath)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-ython3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 773, in visit_If
    self.generic_visit(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 415, in generic_visit
    self.visit(item)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 417, in generic_visit
    self.visit(value)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 407, in visit
    return visitor(node)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 421, in visit_Constant
    type_name = _const_node_type_names.get(type(value))
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
(base) MacBook-Pro-Admin-2:Folder2 admin$
```

Comment: Нужно устранить ошибку. (Какой вопрос, такой ответ. Будет больше подробностей, будут лучше ответы. :)

Comment: Создайте для вопроса минимальный по объёму пример воспроизводящий ошибку и добавьте его в вопрос.